# why wc -l result is 1 for empty variable

Tags: bash

Given the following bash code

```bash
grep match_nothing file.txt | wc -l
```

The result 0 is correct. But the following code

```bash
LINES=$(grep match_nothing file.txt)
wc -l <<< "$LINES"
```

Will return 1. Why this happens and how can I make it right.

Update:

This question just use `grep` as an example. What confuse me is the why  assign output to a variable leads to a different result.

Comment: [Link to the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) which states "The result is supplied as a single string, with a *newline appended* ...".

Comment: For reference, you can get a count of matching line using `-c`: `grep -c div index.html`.  No need to pipe anything :)

Comment: Even better, use `grep -q`. See also [useless use of `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: @tripleee You meant "*useless use of wc -l*", right? `grep -q` is still grep :)

Comment: FWIW I think the OP is asking about the behavior of `<<<`, not how to get a count of matching lines from running `grep` - that's just a [mcve] to demonstrate the difference in behavior between `... | wc -l` and `wc -l <<< ...`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding:

> Why this happens

The purpose of a here-string is to convert a string into something that a tool can read as input as if it were reading a file and, per POSIX, a valid text file always ends in a Line Feed and so the here-string construct adds a Line Feed to the end of the string. If it didn't do that then it's output wouldn't be a valid POSIX text "file" and so you couldn't reliably use it as input to any text-processing tool such as sed, awk, etc.

Regarding:

> and how can I make it right

It already is right but if you don't want a Line Feed added then use command substitution with a `printf` to produce the input:

```
$ lines=''

$ wc -l <<< "$lines"
1

$ wc -l < <(printf '%s' "$lines")
0
```

but be aware the output is then not a valid text file per POSIX and YMMV regarding how various tools will handle it, e.g. given a non-empty string:

```
$ lines='foo'
```

The typical expected behavior would be provided by a here-string:

```
$ wc -l <<< "$lines"
1

$ while IFS= read -r var; do echo "$var"; done <<< "$lines"
foo
```

while using command substitution with a `printf` would probably not be what you'd expect:

```
$ wc -l < <(printf '%s' "$lines")
0

$ while IFS= read -r var; do echo "$var"; done < <(printf '%s' "$lines")
$
```

If you want to provide input that has a Line Feed added when the variable is populated but doesn't otherwise then you could consider something like:

```
$ lines=''

$ wc -l < <(printf '%s' "$lines"; (( ${#lines} )) && printf '\n')
0

$ while IFS= read -r var; do echo "$var"; done < <(printf '%s' "$lines"; (( ${#lines} )) && printf '\n')
$
```

```
$ lines='foo'

$ wc -l < <(printf '%s' "$lines"; (( ${#lines} )) && printf '\n')
1

$ while IFS= read -r var; do echo "$var"; done < <(printf '%s' "$lines"; (( ${#lines} )) && printf '\n')
foo
```

Comment: Thank you for the detail explanation, now I see what happens and I can add an `grep . ` to filter empty line in my use case.