# Why does while read loop run when the input string is empty?

Tags: bash

```bash
#!/bin/bash

LINES=$(grep matchnothing file.txt)

while read it; do
echo 'find line'
echo $it
done <<< "$LINES"
```

I would expect the code above to print nothing, but it will print 'find line' even if `$it` is empty. How can I fix this to make it work as expected?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78051930/3776858

Comment: With `LINES=…`, you assign a string to that variable. The content of the string may be empty, but it's still a string. Same with `<<< "$LINES"`: The `"…"` provides a string, even if there is no character content, it's still one string that makes its way to `read`.

Comment: Re "How can I fix this to make it work as expect?": Depends on what you expect. You could test the variable beforehand if it has zero length. Or take `grep`'s exit code and make the subsequent processing depend on it using `LINES="$(grep …)" && …`, etc.

Comment: Also, don't use all-caps variable names, as they might conflict with shell or environment variables. In the case of Bash (as tagged), `LINES` is actually used to provide the height (number of rows) of the console screen or GUI terminal window.